# Ruby split a long string of characters into actual words

Tags: ruby

I've got an array of strings which contains 2 elements: first is a sequence of characters and the second will be a long string of comma-separated words, in alphabetical order that represents dictionary of some arbitrary length. Now I want to check if from the list of words of the second element I can create the word of the first element in the array.

Below example will better illustrate what I mean:

```
string_array = ["baseball", "a,all,b,ball,bas,base,cat,code,d,e,quit,z"]
Output: base,ball
```

so What I did is simple method:

```
def word_split(string_array)
  splitted_arr = string_array[1].split(',')
  strArr.include?(splitted_arr)
end
```

but it gives me only `false` result. How to compare those string in array?

Comment: If I assume that `strArr` should be `string_array`, your code doesn't do what you describe in words. Think about this sentence for a minute: "Now I want to check if from the list of words of the second element I can create the word of the first element in the array." What parts of this are you missing?

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  For the input `["foobar","foo,bar,bat"]` you would want to return true, because "foobar" can be formed by concatenating "foo" and "bar".  For the input `["foobar","foob,bar,bat"]` you would want to return false.  Right?  Seems like you will have to do some search algorithm with backtracking.

Comment: @DavidGrayson for `["foobar","foo,bar,bat"]` I want to return `foo,bar` and if there is no way to split string into two words that exist in the `splitted_arr`, return the string `not possible`

Comment: I could just write all this code for you in 5 minutes but I bet you can figure it out with some prodding.  As a first step, do you know what you do to figure out all the possible *first words* in the output?  So if I give you `["foobar", "foo,foob,cat"]` can you return to me `["foo", "foob"]`?

Comment: @DavidGrayson in case of `["foobar", "foo,foob,cat"]` you should return `not possible` string because you cannot create a word `"foobar"` from `"foo,foob,cat"`

Comment: You're jumping all the way to final answer but I'm trying to show how to get there one step at a time.  I think the first step is to identify candidates for what the first word of the final answer could be.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I assume it has to be some kind of `each_with_object` iteration where you check if `foobar ` includes each word of `splitted_arr`. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2):

I made a method that takes two arguments: a word and an array of words.  You can easily make a wrapper function that operates on the data structure you proposed, if you want.

```rb
def find_sequence(target, words)
  return [] if target.empty?
  words.each do |word|
    if target.start_with?(word)
      # We found a good candidate for the first word, so let's recurse
      # and see if we can find the rest of the words.
      remainder = target.sub(word, '')  # remove word from start of target
      seq = find_sequence(remainder, words)
      return [word] + seq if seq
    end
  end
  nil
end

# Example 1: your example
s = ["baseball", "a,all,b,ball,bas,base,cat,code,d,e,quit,z"]
p find_sequence(s[0], s[1].split(","))  # ["bas", "e", "b", "all"]

# Example 2: no solution
p find_sequence("foobar", ["foo", "cat"])  # nil

# Example 3: backtracking
p find_sequence("abcde", ["abcd","abc","ab","a","d","bcde"])  # ["a", "bcde"]
```

By the way, this is an example of a depth first search.

Comment: it returns more than two words.